# How to add class in rails 2.3.5 to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have got following link_to tag But I don't know how to add html class attribute to it and explain me code edit_course_path(course) .. does. I am new to rails

```
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <li class="list<%=cycle('odd', 'even')%>">
         <div class="category-edit"><%= link_to "#{t('edit_text')}", edit_course_path(course) if permitted_to? :edit, :courses %></div>
         <div class="category-delete">   <%= link_to(t('delete_text'), course_path(course), :method => 'delete', :confirm => "#{t('delete_confirm_msg')}") if permitted_to? :destroy, :courses %></div>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally like so:

```
<% for employee in @employees %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_employee_path(employee) if permitted_to? :update, employee , :class => 'some-class'%>
<% end %>
```